# C++ if statement not printing desired output

Tags: c++, if-statement

Problem is with the if statment inside the while loop. It is not printing the desired output. The else if statement and the else statement seem to work fine
Any help is appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*
  Write a C++ program that asks the user for an integer. 
  The program finds and displays the first power of 3 
  larger than the input number using while 

*/
int main() {
  int input = 0;
  int base = 3;
  int exponent = 0;
  int sum = 1;

  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;

  while (sum < input) {
    // This is the if statement giving me problems
    if (input == 1) {
      exponent += 1;
      sum = 3;
    }
    // This else if statement seems to work fine
    else if (input == 3) {
      exponent += 2;
      sum = 9;
    }
    else {
      exponent++;
      sum *= base;
    }
  }
  // Print output 
  cout << "3 to the power of " << exponent << " is equal to " << sum;
  cout << endl << "It is the first power of 3 larger than " << input;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you input 1, i need it print 3 for the sum

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong (and I have to say a bit bizarre).

If the `input` is `1` then `while (sum < input)` is not true and so you never reach your `if (input == 1)` statement.

Answer (score 1):

REALIZED my mistake. i just moved the if and else if statement to outside the loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*
  Write a C++ program that asks the user for an integer. 
  The program finds and displays the first power of 3 
  larger than the input number using while 

*/
int main() {
  int input = 0;
  int base = 3;
  int exponent = 0;
  int sum = 1;

  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;

      if (input == 1) {
      exponent += 1;
      sum = 3;
    }
    else if (input == 3) {
      exponent += 2;
      sum = 9;
    }
  while (sum < input) {

      exponent++;
      sum *= base;
  }

  cout << "3 to the power of " << exponent << " is equal to " << sum;
  cout << endl << "It is the first power of 3 larger than " << input;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the objective right from the comments, `if` conditions are not required. Just replace the condition and simplify the `while` loop as follows:

```cpp
  while (sum <= input) {
    exponent++;
    sum *= base;
  }
```

Comment: Both your question and answer are wrong, but if you change either of them to @programmer answer you should at least get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a C++ program that asks the user for an integer. The program
>   finds and displays the first power of 3 larger than the input number
>   using while

You should probably calculate the answer instead of looping.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int input;
    std::cout << "input: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    int x = 0;

    /*    
          3^x == input
      ln(3^x) == ln(input)
      x*ln(3) == ln(input)
            x == ln(input)/ln(3)
    */

    // calculate x = ln(input)/ln(3),  round down and add 1
    if(input > 0) x = std::floor(std::log(input) / std::log(3.)) + 1.;

    std::cout << "answer: 3^" << x << " == " << std::pow(3, x) << "\n";
}
```